# Cygwin g++ build error: undefined reference to

Tags: netbeans, g++, cygwin, undefined-reference

I was trying to build a project ([rar file](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~b98902109/db/btree12.rar)) with NetBeans cygwin g++ compiler.
I could build it by running `make` in the **src/** directory under ubuntu. However, under cygwin, it kept giving me `undefined reference to...`.

(Before compiling, I had changed `CC = g++` to `CC = g++-3` in **src/Makefile**. )

The error said that `undefined reference to BufMgr::pinPage(int, Page*&, int, char const*)`, where `pinPage()` was located at the **include/**.

Here's the structure of the project.

```
project/
    include/
        buf.h (where pinPage() was defined)
        other header files
    src/
        Makefile
        other source files
```

Following are the origin Makefile and the error.

Makefile:

```
#
# Makefile for CS564 Minibase project.  Needs GNU make.
#
# Define DEBUGREL for some kind of debugging output (not from us, from
# the original Minibase implementors.)
#
# Warning: make depend overwrites this file.

.PHONY: depend clean backup setup

MAIN = btree

MINIBASE = ..

CC = g++

#CFLAGS = -DUNIX -Wall -g
CFLAGS = -g

INCLUDES = -I${MINIBASE}/include -I.

LFLAGS = -L. -lbtree -lm

SRCS = main.C btree_driver.C btfile.C btindex_page.C btleaf_page.C btree_file_scan.C key.C db.C new_error.C sorted_page.C system_defs.C

OBJS = $(SRCS:.C=.o)

$(MAIN):  $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) $(OBJS) -o $(MAIN) $(LFLAGS)

.C.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -c $<

depend: $(SRCS)
    makedepend $(INCLUDES) $^

clean:
    rm -f *.o *~ $(MAIN)
    rm -f my_output

backup:
    -mkdir bak
    cp Makefile *.[Ch] bak

run:
    rm -rf my_output
    ./btree > my_output

# Grab the sources for a user who has only the makefile
setup:
    /bin/cp -i $(MINIBASE)/src/*.[Ch] .
    /bin/cp -i $(MINIBASE)/src/*.sample .

# DO NOT DELETE THIS LINE -- make depend needs it
```

Erorr:

```
$ make
g++-3 -g -I../include -I. -c main.C
g++-3 -g -I../include -I. -c btree_driver.C
g++-3 -g -I../include -I. -c btfile.C
g++-3 -g -I../include -I. -c btindex_page.C
g++-3 -g -I../include -I. -c btleaf_page.C
g++-3 -g -I../include -I. -c btree_file_scan.C
g++-3 -g -I../include -I. -c key.C
g++-3 -g -I../include -I. -c db.C
g++-3 -g -I../include -I. -c new_error.C
g++-3 -g -I../include -I. -c sorted_page.C
g++-3 -g -I../include -I. -c system_defs.C
g++-3 -g -I../include -I. main.o btree_driver.o btfile.o btindex_page.o btleaf_page.o btree_file_scan.o key.o db.o new_error.o sorted_page.o system_defs.o -o btree -L. -lbtree -lm
btfile.o: In function `_ZN9BTreeFileC2ER6StatusPKc':
/cygdrive/c/Users/Trantor/Documents/NetBeansProjects/DB-HW6/src/btfile.C:78: undefined reference to `BufMgr::pinPage(int, Page*&, int, char const*)'
btfile.o: In function `_ZN9BTreeFileC1ER6StatusPKc':
/cygdrive/c/Users/Trantor/Documents/NetBeansProjects/DB-HW6/src/btfile.C:78: undefined reference to `BufMgr::pinPage(int, Page*&, int, char const*)'
btfile.o: In function `_ZN9BTreeFileC2ER6StatusPKc8AttrTypeii':

.....
```

Comment: It's impossible to say what the problem is because you don't show the complete error. However, it can be inferred that it's a linker error, which means that there is an object file or a library that you need to link with but doesn't.

Comment: I had appended the error and project dir structure to the question.

Comment: Is the missing function _fully defined_ in the header file, or is there are source file accompanying the header file?

Comment: No. **include/buf.h** defined BufMgr::pinPage() as `Status pinPage(int PageId_in_a_DB, Page*& page, int emptyPage=0, const char *filename=NULL);`. And neither in **src/** or **include/** fully defined the function.

Comment: So there is actually no implementation of this function?

Comment: On my linux, `g++ -v` shows `gcc version 4.7.2 (Debian 4.7.2-4)`. On cygwin, however, is g++-3. Does that makes difference?

Comment: Terminology correction: functions are usually **declared** in .h file (`int func();`), and **defined** in a .c/.cpp file (`int func() { /*code*/ }`). Technially you can define symbol in a .h file, but linker will complain about multiple definitions if you include such .h file in many .c/.cpp files (unless it is `static`, in which case linker will not even see it).

Comment: Thanks, @hyde. And I found that g++-4 makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

This may be, because file extension seems to be `.C`.  On case-sensitive file systems (Unix), capital `.C` extension means C++ code, while lower case `.c` means plain old C code. So compiler may try to compile it as C code, which will produce different function names.

If this is the reason, then possible fixes:

- Force gcc to compile C++ by adding right compile switch to CFLAGS (`-x c++`, says quick googling)
- Rename files to `.cpp`, and fix extensions in Makefile too

Comment: I tried `-x c++`. But it gave me `main.o:1:1: error: stray ‘\1’ in program
main.o:1:1: error: stray ‘\20’ in program
main.o:1:4: warning: null character(s) ignored
main.o:1:1: error: stray ‘\210’ in program
main.o:1:11: warning: null character(s) ignored
main.o:1:14: warning: null character(s) ignored
....`

Comment: @trantor Do not give CFLAGS to link command. Alternatively, add that `-x` directly to the compile command line.

Comment: Thanks. But it turned out to be the origin error (it already treated them as .cpp).